# JMeter method call on start/end of test plan

Tags: java, jmeter

I am looking to make a combination JMeter extensions that satisfy a few criteria:

1. Open files at the beginning of the test plan/thread group. One of the files in an excel file used for input. I have the code to read it using apache poi via including the apache tika jar in the jmeter `lib` folder. The input should then be used in the threads as variables just like it's done with the `CSV Data Set Config` test element.
2. Aggregate all results at the end of the test plan/thread group to do calculations on the set of all results.

For #1, Maybe it is possible to do this by extending a config element but I haven't seen how to do this yet. I am also unsure of how to mimic the behaviour of `CSV Data Set Config`.

For #2 the purpose is to send the final information extracted from the results to a server so saving results to a file is not optimal. The `View Results Tree` or the `View Results in Table` elements both create a report of all results so it seems it should be possible to do this.

Edit:
How to achieve the above?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question as **'How to achieve the above?'**

**For #1:**

First of, I believe it is much easier/simpler (because *Simple is better than complex*) to get the excel/app to provide csv file for jmeter to consume it using `CSV Data Set Config`. I mean, write the reading logic somewhere else which will feed into jmeter's test data file. Another option would be to write a [JSR223 sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in a [set up threadgroup](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to read the excel and produce the CSV.

But if you need it anyhow, you will need to write a custom plugin which will inherit from `ConfigTestElement` and will need to implement `TestBean` and `LoopIterationListener` interfaces. Good place to start is [here.](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) And the code for `CSV Data Set Config` is [here.](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/config/CSVDataSet.java)

**For #2:**

If you need `POST` the result file to server then you can use a [tearDown thread group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) in jmeter which will pick up the file at the end of the test and do a HTTP post request using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Hope I gave you some direction.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Using the first method you suggested I would like to set some properties in the setUp thread group. The problem is that it seems as though `CSV Data Set Config` runs before the setUp thread group. Is this true and there is no way to add properties during the setUp thread group for use in the config elements? Also the property that I set in the setUp thread group JSR223 sampler using for example, `props.put("csv", csv);` is not preserved for the main thread group: `props.get("csv")` (returns null)

Comment: Yes you are right, CSV Data Set Config runs before any of the threadgroups. If you want to set it during the launch of jmeter you can do so by passing it in command line args (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) and access it by jmeter function like this by using `${__P()}` function (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P). Let me know if you need help.

Comment: I achieved what I wanted by using the `${__groovy()}` function in the `filename` field for `CSV Data Set Config` and called my code to create the csv file and return the new files' name